# vmnet0 it not coming up in RHEL

Tags: vmware-player

I want to install vmplayer with bridging on RHEL 5 but somehow vmnet0 is not comming up when (ifconfig) i read some articles and it says that
vmware bridging protocol may not be enbled on NICs.
Can some one please tell me how to enable this protocol on linux and if there is some other problem.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Do you possibly have to run vmware-config.pl so vmware can compile the appropriate kernel modules for your kernel version?